# Rails net:http PUT request - curl - Tika server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, apache-tika, net-http

I have a remote TIKA server set up and I'm trying to use it from within a RoR application.  I need to pull a file from a remote location and send it on to the Tika server.  The wiki for TikaJAXRS gives an example using curl, but I have not been able to get that to work.  What does work is this:

curl https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/testdocument.docx | curl -v -i -X PUT -T - ec2...154.uswest2.compute.amazonaws.com:9998/tika

How do I render this in my Rails app using net::http?  I've successfully written a GET request with net::http to the Tika server from the Rails app and gotten back the expected result, but the documentation on PUT is a bit sparse. (The server does require a PUT rather than POST.)

BTW, if anyone knows how to make that last example in that wiki work and render it in net::http, that would be even better!

**Addendum:**

Here's what I have in the RoR app that doesn't work:

```
 ENDPOINT = "http://ec2...154.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9998"
 file = "https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/testdocument.docx"
 uri = URI.parse(endpoint)
 @http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 request = Net::HTTP::Put.new("/tika")
 request.body = URI.parse(file).read
 @response = @http.request(request)
```

and I get back a code 415

I need to know how to change this code to do what the curl commands (curl remote_file piped to curl PUT) are doing successfully.

**Update**

After a couple of days of fruitless attempts on this, I have a workaround:

gem 'curb'

```
 @response = Curl.put("http://ec2...154.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9998/tika",
                 Curl.get("https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/testdocument.docx").body_str)
```

While this does provide a solution to my immediate problem,  I still want to know how to implement this same functionality more directly by using Net::HTTP.

Comment: What do you need to render in the Rails application ? Seems straightforward to pull and the PUT via Curl or Net/HTTP.

Comment: I need to replace the curl commands (can't really do those directly within the ruby code) with a    request = Net::HTTP::Put.new()  but I can't seem to get the file properly set into that PUT command.  I need a code example.